# How to add subject alternative name when converting PEM certificate to DER format?

Tags: openssl, x.509, pem, der

Is it possible to add a **subject alternative name** when converting PEM certificate to DER format.

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in Certificate.pem -out Certificate.der -extensions SAN -subject-alternative-name 'alternative name'
```

If possible, so how to make this operation with openssl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, of course not, this would change the certificate and invalidate the signature. You're asking the exact same thing as "I have a certificate for a domain I own, chedy.com, and I want to add google.com to the Subject Alt Names list, what is the openssl command for that?".

The difference between DER and PEM is just a base64 encoding.

You need to generate a new certificate with the SAN you want.